# Reversing video protocol for chinese drone so i can view the stream outside of the app

Tags: disassembly, android, java

I am trying to view the video stream of the [vento protocol air drone](http://www.protocolny.com/protocol-air/drones/with-camera/vento-wifi-drone.html) on my computer.  The final goal is to get the video stream into python or c++ for opencv; however, if i can just view it in a window that would work too.  This is my first reverse engineering project ever.

The drone communicates with the phone over wifi, It creates a hotspot which the phone connects to. Then through the [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.udirc.rcventowifi&hl=en_US) you can view the video and also control the drone.  The first thing i did was port scan it and found out it had udp port 67 (for dhcp I think) and 49153. I also captured the wireless traffic between my phone when I was streaming the video, but not controlling, in an attempt to identify what protocol it was using and implement it on the pc.  In the capture it has a bunch of udp packets of length 1516 coming from the drone to the phone and a few smaller packets.  I think the bigger packets are the video. There are also a bunch of 802.11 packets being exchanged between the drone and the phone, even after the initial connection. I tried decoder the larger udp packets for a few different video streaming protocols but they all just made junk.  [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1t13CABSVWU9DDBeHxcv0U1MnDJYdlMJL) is a tar of the capture.

I also looked into decompiling the app.  I couldn't manage to get anything id consider usable out of it.  Every class was the exact same with a single call to another method and passed a bunch of numbers. But I couldn't decompile that class.

Also looking inside of the drone the wifi seems to be controlled with a marvell 88w8801-nmde.

While it would be great if someone just told me the protocol, i would appreciate just as much someone pointing me in the right direction as this is a good learning opportunity I think.

Comment: I am trying to accomplish a similar goal, working with an Android app that contains a set of C++ shared objects that apparently handle the connection that I am trying to emulate. I just posted a related question on Stackoverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56281339/how-should-i-send-the-magic-packet-to-my-drone-with-scapy

Answer (score 3):

Dowload the apk and open it in [jadx](https://github.com/skylot/jadx) or any such decompiler tool. The app is not obfuscated. package `com.lewei.lib` looks promising with classes like `VideoPlayer`, `FlyCtrl`, `H264Frame` etc. On looking closely it can be seen that the app is trying to load multiple native libraries using `System.loadLibrary`. These .so files can be found in `lib` directory once the apk is unzipped. You'll need a good disassembler/decompiler(like IDA) to analyze these native libraries. Also you can try to find sources for liblewei over the internet.